# How to customize html message <input type=“file”>?

Tags: html, file-upload, input

I am trying to customize the message of my input type file that already looks like this:

[image: http://www.hangar-hosting.com/descargas/01.png]

i need to vertical align middle that "not file chosen" and change the text of both "choose file" and "no file chosen"

Comment: Is this the normal rendering of a file input in your browser, or have you already replaced it with a custom solution?

Comment: Looks like a shadow-dom thingie; check http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/ and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

Answer (score 2):

you can customize like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
#upload-file-container input {
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;   
}
</style>

<br />
<label>Please click the Image to Upload a file:</label>
<div id="upload-file-container">
<input type="file" name="photo" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5rp5e/2/  (Working example)

```
 <div id="background">
<input type="file" value="choose file" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background{
    padding:20px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 300px; /* or whatever you want it to be */
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? What is wrong with this answer - it looks just like his image.

Comment: @Doorknob You must have misread my code or messed something up on your end - it works fine. I just tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding as in Evan's example works to vertically align the text. The text itself is being generated by the system:

http://community.mybb.com/thread-59344.html